# Magento Indexing fails with product price “Cannot initialize the indexer process. ”

Tags: magento-1.9, product, indexing, product-prices

Indexing problem with product price index.

Command Prompt error:

> Product Prices index process unknown error SQLSTATE[21SO1]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in

Admin error:

> Cannot initialize the indexer process.

Solution already tried:

1. Database repair tool.
2. Rename `local.xml` and reinstalled Magento.
3. Indexing using command line.
4. And other solutions which I got on Google.

Please share if any one having working solution for same.